# Revoke token for iOS Guideline 5.1.1 (v)

Tags: ios, firebase

My app received message about ios-guidline-5.1.1(v) from Apple.

Our app includes Sign in with Apple(through firebase) and the membership withdrawal function,
but not revoke token.

So, I handled to call Auth.auth().currentUser.delete() Firebase function
when user try withdraw from membership.

Calling Auth.auth().currentUser.delete() was not delete
from list of Apps using Apple id on Device's Setting.

Is this the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apple's revoke API requires a JWT signed with the developer's key, it cannot be processed only by the client.

Before Firebase officially supports it, you need to configure the server yourself, and you can implement it through Firebase's Functions. Please see the link below.

https://github.com/jooyoungho/apple-token-revoke-in-firebase